# make linux directory writable using bash command through java code

Tags: java, linux, bash, sh

I have a directory /webroot in my linux server. Which permission set is 771, that means 1 for others. But I want to make it 773 through java code which like is :

```
Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 773 /webroot");
```

But it can not change the permission.

I also capture the error stream which is like as :

```
chmod: changing permissions of `/webroot/': Operation not permitted
```

I saw a nearly related post yesterday, but i could not find the appropriate answer. At this time, what can I do now?

Please any help.

Comment: Look into gaining OS permissions, I think it might help

Comment: If you dont mind, can you please let me know more details? I am totally new in linux server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the error is pretty clear here.  What user is your Java code running as?  It most likely doesn't have permissions to run `chmod` on that directory.

Do a `ls -l` on that directory to see who it is owned by.  Make sure that your Java code is running at that same user.

Comment: All permission are as follows : `drwxrwx--x 9 root root 4096 Dec  7 09:47 webroot `, But how I can run java code using root user?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it.  You may be able to use sudo.  Otherwise, maybe this is an initial setup that you need to complete outside of Java.

Comment: Hey I used `Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sudo chmod 773 /webroot");` but it cant change directory permission and captured error stream is as follows: `sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo `

Comment: @Pritom its strange what you're trying to do - I'd suggest sticking with ziesemer's suggestions.. but if you really want to hammer away you'll need to edit the sudoers file and include a !requiretty for your user

Comment: I am using tomcat6 and username is 'tomcat', now what could I add to my `sudoers` file???