# How do you set user work as root in Linux, when the bash script runs via Java code

Tags: java, linux, bash, permissions

Suppose my bash file contains

```
chmod -R 777 $backup_files/app/webroot/uploadedFiles/
```

It works fine when I run it through root permission using `/permission.sh` but when I try to run this bash script via java code like

```
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process process = runtime.exec("/permission.sh");
        printBufferedReaderOutputFromProcess(process);
        process.waitFor();
```

It gives me the following error:

```
chmod: changing permissions of `/home/app/webroot/uploadedFiles/A.jpg': Operation not permitted
```

What can I fix it?

Comment: Duplicate of [make linux directory writable using bash command through java code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410360/make-linux-directory-writable-using-bash-command-through-java-code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you haven't use sudo before, however an alternative to using the setuid on the script is to give the user the right to sudo the script as root. i.e.

```
sudo permisions.sh
```

This runs as root can can be run without asking a password. You have to set this up in sudoers.conf

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Have you ever heard about setuid scripts?!? OMG! However sudo advise is OK (however `sudo` requires full path to the script if it is not in `PATH` e.g. `sudo ./permisions.sh`).

Comment: My first suggestion was to use a setuid script, however these can be hard to control who can run it and manage in any centralise way.

Answer (score 0):

How are you running your Java code?  Is it stand-alone, or running in a web container like Tomcat?  If the later, it's probably running as a user that doesn't have permissions to the directory you're trying to change.

Comment: Yes, I am runnig java code through tomcat6 and user name is tomcat, I added the following line in sudoers `tomcat ALL=(ALL)  NOPASSWD: ALL`

Comment: Are you calling sudo somewhere, maybe as part of `permission.sh`?  (It doesn't just work automatically.)

Comment: Pritom: You should change your Jave code to `runtime.exec("sudo /permission.sh");`. Perhaps being more strict is good idea: `tomcat ALL = NOPASSWD: /permission.sh`.

Comment: When I write `runtime.exec("sudo /permission.sh");` then it shows `sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo`. And when I write this in sudoers `tomcat ALL = NOPASSWD: /permission.sh` then it shows `chmod: changing permissions of /app/webroot/uploadedFiles/': Operation not permitted`

Comment: It may be possible to resovle the "sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo" issue by adding `!requiretty` to the directive in your `sudoers` file.  However, similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410360/make-linux-directory-writable-using-bash-command-through-java-code , I really question the overall approach here.  Maybe this is an initial setup that you need to complete outside of Java.